# New unity input system, error using InputValue.isPressed with a gamepad joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created an input action named "Jump", using a gamepad joystick as the binding.

First, I tried using this code:

```
   void OnJump(InputValue value)
{
    
    if (!capsuleCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (value.isPressed)
    {
        playerRb.velocity += new Vector2(0f, jumpForce);
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

*InvalidOperationException: Cannot read value of type 'float' from control '/Gamepad/rightStick' bound to action 'Player/Jump[/Gamepad/rightStick]' (control is a 'StickControl' with value type 'Vector2')*

Since I wasn't sure how to fix it, I switched to the following code:

```
   void OnJump(InputValue value)
{
    Vector2 inputValue = value.Get<Vector2>();
    float yValue = inputValue.y;
    bool pressedUp = yValue > Mathf.Epsilon;

    if (!capsuleCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (pressedUp)
    {
        playerRb.velocity += new Vector2(0f, jumpForce);
    }
}
```

This works, but I've noticed that the jump force applied depends on how fast you move the joystick up:

[image]

I am not sure how to tell the game object to apply the "jumpForce" once as soon as the joystick is moved up no matter how fast you do it

Comment: You mean like if y>0 addforce?

Comment: @BugFinder yes, that works but it seems to add the force more than one time when I move the joystick up